# JQuery button click not registering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

I have created a mock twitter website that is supposed to generate more tweets once a button is clicked. I have created the button which is appended to the main section of the site but it seems that once it is clicked absolutely nothing happens. I have looked this over and over again making sure that my code is correct but I am afraid that I am just missing something. below is a my JQuery and CSS.

JQuery:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var $body = $('body');
    var $section = $('.main');

    $section.html('');

    //Returns a div with a time stamp for the tweet
    var createdTime = function(tweet){

        return $('<div>', {text: tweet.created_at, id: 'dT'}).prop('outerHTML');

    };
    //Returns the @handle as a link of the user who tweeted
    var userName = function(tweet){
        return $('<a>', {text: tweet.user, href: '#'}).prop('outerHTML') + '<br />' + '@' + tweet.user; 
    };

    // simply returns the users tweeted message
    var tweetContent = function(tweet){
        return tweet.message;
    };

    var index = streams.home.length - 1;
    // A function that generates new tweets
    var newTweets = function(index){
    while(index >= 0){
            var tweet = streams.home[index];
            var $tweet = $('<div class=tweet></div>');
            //call to outside function to populate tweets
            $tweet.html(userName(tweet) + ': ' + tweetContent(tweet) + createdTime(tweet));
            $tweet.appendTo($section);
            index -= 1;

        }
    }
    newTweets(index);
    //Adds a user image to tweet  
   $('.tweet').prepend('<img id=tweetImg src=images/blank-user.jpg />');

    //button created to generate more tweets after page has loaded
   var $button = $('<button />', {
       type: 'button',
       'class':'tweetButton',
       id: 'mT',
       text: 'More Tweets',
       click: function(){
          index = streams.home.length-1;
           newTweets(index);
           alert('I work!');
       }
   });
      $button.appendTo($section);

  });
```

CSS:

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, caption {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}

body{
    background-color: #D7DADB;
    font-family: 'Asar', serif;
    position: relative;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Header
  ========================================
*/
nav{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 28px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #6DBCDB;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #F1433F;
    
}
a,
nav{
    padding: 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Typography
  ========================================
*/

/*
  ========================================
  Button
  ========================================
*/
button{
    width: 300px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 10px auto 100px auto;
    background-color: #F1433F;
    border: none;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    font-family: 'Asar', serif;
    font-size: large;
    font-style: oblique;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.tweetButton{
    
}
.search{
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    right: 20px;
    
}
#srchFrm{
    height: 20px;
    width:170px;
    padding-left: 10px; 
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #D7DADB;
    font-family: 'Asar', serif;
}

#srchBtn{
    height: 25px;
    width: 80px;
    position: relative;
    right: 4px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    background-color: #F1433F;
    font-family: 'Asar', serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;   
}

/*
  ========================================
  Imgages
  ========================================
*/
#network{
    position: relative;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-70%);
}


/*
  ========================================
  User
  ========================================
*/

aside{
    position: fixed;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    height: inherit;
    width:300px;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(#2C3E50,#415B75,#6DBCDB, #EEEEEE);
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    text-align: center;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #F1433F; 
}
#user-pic{
    clear:both;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 20px;
}
#trend{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    height: 400px;
    width: 270px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    border-top: 1px solid #F1433F;
}
/*
  ========================================
  Main
  ========================================
*/
.container{
    margin-top: 80px;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Middle Content
  ========================================
*/

section{
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 400px;
    z-index: -1;
    
    
}
.main{
    background-color: #D7DADB;
}
/*
  ========================================
  Tweet Box
  ========================================
*/
#tweetImg{
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.tweet a{
    font-size: large;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
.tweet a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: gray;
}
.tweet{
    position: relative;
    width: 450px;
    height: 225px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 4px solid #F1433F;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 25px 15px 0px 15px;
}
.tweetContent{
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    margin: 5px 5px 0 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    border-top: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
}

#dT{
    width:inherit;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: small;
}
```

===============UPDATE============================

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="twittler.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asar' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="data_generator.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <header>
          <nav>
              <form class="search">
                  <input type="text" id='srchFrm' placeholder="Search Twittler" required>
                  <input type ="button" value="Search" id="srchBtn">
              </form>
              <h2>
                  <a href="#">HOME</a>
                  <a href="#">NAVIGATION</a>
                  <a href="#">MESSAGES</a>
              </h2>
              <img id='network' src="images/Network.png">
          </nav>
        </header>
      <div class='container'>
          <aside>
              <img id="user-pic" src="images/blank-user.jpg">
              <a href="#">@User_Name</a>
              <div id="trend"><h6>TRENDING</h6></div>
              
          </aside>
          <section class="main">
          </section>
     </div>
      


    <script>
              *************JQUERY********

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why  don't you use `on`

Comment: I can't see any button in your code snippet ? Am i missing something ?

Comment: It is at the very bottom of my JQuery code portion.

Comment: I saw it in the code , i'm talking about the working snippet. It's not there.

Comment: Your code doesn't create any button. https://jsfiddle.net/tq6jq999/

Comment: It does on my end....did you include the CSS?

Comment: @DLF85 Yes. Check in my fiddle link

Comment: @ketan that is because this code is within html. I did not post the html that would show the actual page.

Comment: @DLF85 Then please include html also. and post then link,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the button creation part to this

```
var $button = $('<button />', {
       type: 'button',
       class:'tweetButton',
       id: 'mT',
       text: 'More Tweets'
   });
```

and add the following after that.

```
$(document).on('click',".tweetButton",function() {
   index = streams.home.length-1;
   newTweets(index);
   alert('I work!');
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/soorajchn/cjq5jmw9/) that demonstrates the example

Comment: This does not work because it does not generate a button dynamically.

Comment: This should be used after you create the button , remove the click event from the dynamic generation part and add this.

Comment: Can you change the fiddle so that the button you are referring to appears in it.

Comment: Yes please go forward.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104238/discussion-between-dlf85-and-sooraj-chandran).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
$('.main').on('click', '#mT', function(){
  index = streams.home.length-1;
  newTweets(index);
  alert('I work!');
});
```

Comment: This does not produce anything. In the original code that I posted everything is being generated within button (class, id, and <button>).

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `z-index: -1;` from `section` then button click work for you.

```
section{
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 400px; 
//    z-index: -1; // remove it
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tq6jq999/1/)**

Comment: @DLF85 check in fiddle link. It display alert message.